# Android check internet connection in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to check if the device have internet connection, I search for some examples but when i copy and paste the code i always get errors or deprecated function. I also not understand where I have to put the method that check the connection, because I need to check the internet connection in the viewModel to make some request, and all the methods that i found have Context in the parameters, and I can't get Context in viewModel.

I try this code but I don't understand where I have to put it and I get

`'TYPE_WIFI, TYPE_MOBILE, TYPE_ETHERNET: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java`

```
private fun isInternetAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
        var result = false
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
            val actNw =
                connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(networkCapabilities) ?: return false
            result = when {
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                else -> false
            }
        } else {
            connectivityManager.run {
                connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
                    result = when (type) {
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI -> true
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE -> true
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET -> true
                        else -> false
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return result
    }
```

Someone can explain me how to make this check?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the relevant documentation page: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/reading-network-state

Answer (score 3):

I created a helper class.
**Network.kt**

```
object Network {
    private const val NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED = 0
    private const val NETWORK_STATUS_WIFI = 1
    private const val NETWORK_STATUS_MOBILE = 2
    private const val TYPE_WIFI = 1
    private const val TYPE_MOBILE = 2
    private const val TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0
    private fun connectivityStatus(context: Context): Int {
        val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if (activeNetwork.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) return TYPE_WIFI
            if (activeNetwork.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) return TYPE_MOBILE
        }
        return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED
    }


    private fun connectivityStatusString(context: Context): Int {
        val connection = connectivityStatus(context)
        var status = -1
        if (connection == TYPE_WIFI) status = NETWORK_STATUS_WIFI else if (connection == TYPE_MOBILE) status = NETWORK_STATUS_MOBILE else if (connection == TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) status = NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED
        return status
    }

    fun checkConnectivity(context : Context):Boolean{
        val status = connectivityStatusString(context)
        return status == NETWORK_STATUS_WIFI || status == NETWORK_STATUS_MOBILE
    }
}
```

and to access it you need to use it like this

```
if (Network.checkConnectivity(this@MainActivity))
    \\Internet is working
else
    \\No internet connectivity
```

Comment: IDE show error on the `@MainActivity` in the `if (Network.checkConnectivity(this@MainActivity))`

Comment: You can use it like if (Network.checkConnectivity(this)) or replaceMainActivity with your current activity name.

Comment: But I use it in the viewModel, and the Activity that contains the Fragment is MainActivity but the IDE show me this error

Comment: The function requires a context. Pass a context to it and the error will disappear.

Comment: What does it matter. This only shows if there is a wifi or mobile connection. Not if they have internet.

Comment: @blackapps i need to check if i have internet, how can I do that?

Comment: @Eyosiyas how i pass a context in the viewmodel? I'm new in android development

Comment: Just try to connect with a server on the internet.

Comment: @blackapps and how i do this?

Comment: Strange question. You want internet. So for what else then connecting with something on the internet i would think.

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend `AndroidViewModel()` class. After that you can reach application context in your `viewModel`.

```
class viewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewModel(app) {}
```